# Where to find "gmp.h"?

Tags: c, makefile

I am installing a library, and got this error message:

```
xxxx@ubuntu$ make
(cd num; make all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxxx/num'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxxx/num'
(cd itv; make all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxxx/itv'
gcc -Wcast-qual -Wswitch -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-unused -std=c99 -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -O3 -DNDEBUG -I../num -I../apron -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -DNUM_MPQ -c -o itvMPQ.o itv.c
In file included from itv.h:9:0,
             from itv.c:5:
../num/num.h:15:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [itvMPQ.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxxx/itv'
make: *** [c] Error 2
```

So the problem is that it can not find `gmp.h`, does anyone know where this file is located, and how to make it found by the installer? By the way, at the moment my `Makefile` points mainly to `/usr` and `/usr/local`...

**Edit1**: After installing `libgmp3-dev` as suggested, the current error message is `../num/num.h:16:18: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory`, does anyone know which package it is about?

**Edit2**: I have installed `MPFR` by following this [page](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Installing-MPFR), and that did help, now the error message is `gmp_caml.c:17:33: fatal error: caml/camlidlruntime.h: No such file or directory`, could anyone help?

**Edit3**: I have done `apt-file search camlidlruntime`, and it returns `camlidl: /usr/lib/ocaml/caml/camlidlruntime.h`, but there is no `camlidlruntime.h` in my folder `/usr/lib/ocaml/caml/`, how could I check if I have installed `dev package of MPFR`? and which package it is exactly about?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

you need to install 
 libgmp3-dev

depends on your linux

```
yum install  libgmp3-dev

apt-get install  libgmp3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... that did help... now error is `../num/num.h:16:18: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory`, so do you know which package it is about?

Comment: please make sure you have all required libs. you need to install GNU MPFR according to error .

Comment: Sure... do you have any idea about the last question i added?

Comment: install dev package of   MPFR . you can use yum or apt-get to find correct package name.

Comment: to compile you will need dev package. user apt search if it shows dev then it is dev package otherwise not

Comment: I have done `apt-file search camlidlruntime`, but it does not show which package is about...

Comment: if you put some time on googling using file name you will find package name for your file.

Comment: i tried yum install  libgmp3-dev but i have the message "You need to be root to perform this command".I am trying this from root but i am not sure if i have permission to do this..Any idea?

Comment: @VivekGoel I got the message "dchris04 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
" where dchris04 is my username.Also,i am not sure if i have password as a root user because i work on my university labs' computers.

Comment: @Dchris then there are two choice ask lab admin to install it or manually compile and build it.

Comment: In Centos 6.5 it is : sudo yum install gmp gmp-devel gmp-status . Just search for the gmp in yum .

Comment: @thedayturns Thanks for testifying. I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 21):

On OS X (if you're using Homebrew), do this:

```
brew install gmp
```

Answer (score 13):

In Centos 6.5 it is `sudo yum install gmp gmp-devel gmp-status`.

ProTip: Just search for the gmp in yum and also check out yum provides command.

Comment: should read
sudo yum install gmp gmp-devel gmp-static

not gmp-status

worked for me after this and was able to compile on Centos 7, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked:-

```
apt-get install  libgmp3-dev   (Might vary in linux distro; this is for Ubuntu)
pip3 install gmpy --user
```

Comment: Yup, this was the missing one for me on Debian. I had installed libgmp-dev, and it had not helped...

Answer (score 4):

Because it can happen that you need this library in 32 bit format for any particular reason (like it was for me)

You will need to run (on an Ubuntu/Debian) :

```
apt-get install  libgmp3-dev:i386
```

the suffix `:i386` behind any library will install the 32 bits version of it.

Answer (score 3):

I did a lot of research and finally I could compile hue with the following environment variables:

```
    export CPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/gmp.h -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
    export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/gmp.h"
    export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/gmp.h"
    export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"

    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may sound kind of dumb:
whenever I got an error , I just did :
`sudo apt-get install lib<name_of_library_not_found>-dev`
and it somehow solved the problem.
Don't Know how, something to do with developer libraries or something