# command 'gcc' failed while installing HUE

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-14.04, hue

I am trying to install HUE on ubuntu 14 and I get the following error:

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/home/huser/miniconda/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o
src/_fastmath.c:36:18: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gmp.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make[2]: *** [/home/huser/hue/desktop/core/build/pycrypto-2.6.1/egg.stamp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/huser/hue/desktop/core'
make[1]: *** [.recursive-env-install/core] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/huser/hue/desktop'
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

I have installed gcc using

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

I followed the instructions from this [link](http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/). I have installed all the packages listed [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites). Please help!

Comment: Did you tried to install libgmp3-dev:
   sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

Answer (score 5):

This error states that gcc had not found "gmp.h", not that gcc is missing.
You need to assure that you have installed "libgmp3-dev" package and have gmp.h in path.

It is duplicate of [Where to find "gmp.h"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351205/where-to-find-gmp-h), but I seem not to be able to flag this as such.

Comment: And this recent dependency is now listed officially: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/commit/edcbb697e87e223da18f6e0c48b937739ff44408