# mlton gives library-related error

Tags: sml, mlton

When I try to compile a program with `mlton`, I get an error.

```
~/projects/serve-sml $ mlton server.mlb
In file included from /usr/lib/mlton/include/platform.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/lib/mlton/include/common-main.h:16,
                 from /usr/lib/mlton/include/amd64-main.h:11,
                 from /tmp/file86PWQJ.1.c:110:
/usr/lib/mlton/include/cenv.h:137:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "gmp.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
call to system failed with exit status 1:
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I/usr/lib/mlton/targets/self/include -I/usr/lib/mlton/include -O1 -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fomit-frame-pointer -w -m64 -o /tmp/fileg5D5To.o /tmp/file86PWQJ.1.c
~/projects/serve-sml $
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351205/where-to-find-gmp-h), that means I should install `libgmp3-dev`. I've run `apt-get install libgmp3-dev`, and verified that the file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h` exists, but am still getting the same error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing `gcc -v -x c -E -` in your terminal.  This will print out the header file search path that your C compiler is using.  I get something like:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/Users/ml9951/include
.
/usr/local/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

So if I had `gmp.h` in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, then my C compiler would not find it.  I would suggest moving your .h file into a directory that is on this search path (like `/usr/local/include` in my case), or passing in the `-I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` flag, which would require modifying MLton's build scripts.  Chances are you are going to have to do the same thing with `libgmp.a` when it comes time to link

Comment: Correct all-round (and you predicted the `libgmp.a` issue). I've got `nix` running, so my search path was a bit more convoluted. What I ended up doing is symlinking `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a` into `/nix/store/nrxyygy0wqski1klq0305d3h523k41ps-glibc-2.20/lib`, and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h` into `/nix/store/nrxyygy0wqski1klq0305d3h523k41ps-glibc-2.20/include` (both of which are on the search path you showed me how to find). I'm now able to compile as expected. Hopefully nothing explodes as a result of this...