# "Error occurs when install package "gmpy" on pycharm mac version

Tags: python, macos, package, pycharm

for some reason I want to install gmpy2 on my python(version 3.6.0), I tried it on pycharm. [image]

and it gives me an error message like below:
[image]

(i have already installed pip), anyone help me out? thx!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this sort of problem (missing header files) is related to not installing the base code package that the python code is wrapping.  I don't know gmp, but I would try the suggestion here:

[Where to find “gmp.h”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659319/7311767)

Comment: In addition to the `gmp`, you will also need to install the `mpfr` and `mpc` libraries. Since `mpc` requires `gmp` and `mpfr`, it is usually sufficient to just install `mpc`. Note: I maintain `gmpy2` but I'm not familiar with OSX.

Comment: Yeah I installed gmp.h using home-brew, but it's still not working, I think maybe because the gmp.h installed on my another python version -- the mac default version 2.7.x?

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy ? I'm happy to help you troubleshoot but I think an actual issue is better suited than StackOverflow. Once we have a procedure, I'll add an answer.